# How do I find the permission I need for intent-filter action

Tags: android, android-intent, android-permissions

I find that if I want to put some actions in intent-filter of my broadcast receiver, I need to add certain actions. For example, if I add `android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED` to actions

```
<receiver android:name=".listener.SmsListener">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

I need to add this permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
```

I know there exists a mapping between API calls and permissions: http://pscout.csl.toronto.edu/. I'm writing to ask if there's any official or unofficial document to check such mapping between intent-filters and permissions.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: There is no such mapping exists... you have to explore API doc.

Comment: I certainly do find a mapping between API call and permissions here: http://pscout.csl.toronto.edu/. I suppose similar things for intent-filters may exist?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After few exploration I finally found the mapping. Please check [here](http://pscout.csl.toronto.edu/download.php?file=results/jellybean_intentpermissions). Search your intent action string, and you will find the permission it requires.

Comment: Link is broken. Please append the actual content.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no such documentation for Intent-filters and their permissions but here you check some of them take a look at here..

[android permissions](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html)

[Intent filters and intents](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html)

Comment: I do a quick search in both documents. I think they don't mention anything about the permissions of intent-filters.

Comment: There is no such mapping documnets for android..based on your requirement you have to check for their permissions..

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that. But where can I check the permission required for a given intent-filter?

Comment: For this you have to check some of the example on that particlar broadcast in net..no other way..

Comment: I certainly do find a mapping between API call and permissions here: http://pscout.csl.toronto.edu/. I suppose similar things for intent-filters may exist in net?